# Css width the same as height with unknown height

Tags: css

I'm trying to create one of those little fade effects that Google uses at the end of text instead of an ellipsis or simply cutting the text off with `overflow:hidden`.

I do this by creating a :before element, that I position over the right hand side.

Here's the mixin I use:

```
.OverflowFadeRight(@color)
{
    position:relative;

    &:before {
        content:"";
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        width:4.8rem;
        .GradientLTR(transparent; @color);
    }
}
```

This code works, but what I would like to do is set the width to the same as height so it's always proportional, which is 100% the height of the parent.

I've seen techiques which set height based on width, but can it be done this way round?

Comment: Nice solution - I'll see if it works throughout the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that creating a square with `height:100%` using pseudo elements may not be possible.

The way to create a 'responsive square' is to use the `img` tag.

It allows to set the height and it will proportionally auto-adjust its width.

The alternative to that is to use percentage off the width.

Here's a  <kbd>[demo](http://jsbin.com/togepu/edit?html,css,output)</kbd> using either one.

```
<!-- Empty image 1x1 pixels as gif base64 data -->
<div class="OverflowFadeRight2">Real square with img
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `object-fit: contain` to achieve this result.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm struggling to get this to work on my pseudo element, so not sure it's viable in this instance, but a good option nonetheless